# Mesos master setting up

Tags: centos, apache-zookeeper, mesos

I already setting up Zookeeper, Mesos master and slave on my computer, it work, but when I use the same configuration on dedicated servers, I got an issue on the master election.

I just have one master and 2 slaves, so the quorum = 1.
The main issue is when I start the master, it's not elected as leader because there are already one master with IP 127.0.0.1.

I use this command :

```
./mesos-master.sh --ip=172.16.10.11 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --zk=zk://172.16.10.11:2181/mesos --quorum=1 --hostname=172.16.10.11
```

The log for the master :

```
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0608 11:41:27.994071  6163 logging.cpp:188] INFO level logging started!
I0608 11:41:27.994287  6163 main.cpp:237] Build: 2016-06-07 17:52:23 by root
I0608 11:41:27.994300  6163 main.cpp:239] Version: 0.28.2
I0608 11:41:27.994307  6163 main.cpp:242] Git tag: 0.28.2
I0608 11:41:27.994313  6163 main.cpp:246] Git SHA: ceecad69bd9656cf405ca7378ad021c4ad51aaed
I0608 11:41:27.994349  6163 main.cpp:260] Using 'HierarchicalDRF' allocator
I0608 11:41:28.008420  6163 leveldb.cpp:174] Opened db in 13.989064ms
I0608 11:41:28.010076  6163 leveldb.cpp:181] Compacted db in 1.581918ms
I0608 11:41:28.010134  6163 leveldb.cpp:196] Created db iterator in 18237ns
I0608 11:41:28.010195  6163 leveldb.cpp:202] Seeked to beginning of db in 48811ns
I0608 11:41:28.010273  6163 leveldb.cpp:271] Iterated through 3 keys in the db in 64139ns
I0608 11:41:28.010313  6163 replica.cpp:779] Replica recovered with log positions 33 -> 34 with 0 holes and 0 unlearned
I0608 11:41:28.011041  6187 log.cpp:236] Attempting to join replica to ZooKeeper group
I0608 11:41:28.011241  6188 recover.cpp:447] Starting replica recovery
I0608 11:41:28.011683  6163 main.cpp:471] Starting Mesos master
I0608 11:41:28.014093  6183 recover.cpp:473] Replica is in VOTING status
I0608 11:41:28.014225  6183 recover.cpp:462] Recover process terminated
I0608 11:41:28.014282  6182 master.cpp:375] Master 36976def-b8f7-40e8-b843-895cf276bcd2 (172.16.10.11) started on 172.16.10.11:5050
I0608 11:41:28.014310  6182 master.cpp:377] Flags at startup: --allocation_interval="1secs" --allocator="HierarchicalDRF" --authenticate="false" --authenticate_http="false" --authenticate_slaves="false" --authenticators="crammd5" --authorizers="local" --framework_sorter="drf" --help="false" --hostname="172.16.10.11" --hostname_lookup="true" --http_authenticators="basic" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --ip="172.16.10.11" --log_auto_initialize="true" --log_dir="/var/log/mesos" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --max_completed_frameworks="50" --max_completed_tasks_per_framework="1000" --max_slave_ping_timeouts="5" --port="5050" --quiet="false" --quorum="1" --recovery_slave_removal_limit="100%" --registry="replicated_log" --registry_fetch_timeout="1mins" --registry_store_timeout="20secs" --registry_strict="false" --root_submissions="true" --slave_ping_timeout="15secs" --slave_reregister_timeout="10mins" --user_sorter="drf" --version="false" --webui_dir="/usr/share/mesos/webui" --work_dir="/var/lib/mesos" --zk="zk://172.16.10.11:2181/mesos" --zk_session_timeout="10secs"
I0608 11:41:28.014503  6182 master.cpp:424] Master allowing unauthenticated frameworks to register
I0608 11:41:28.014511  6182 master.cpp:429] Master allowing unauthenticated slaves to register
I0608 11:41:28.014521  6182 master.cpp:467] Using default 'crammd5' authenticator
W0608 11:41:28.014533  6182 authenticator.cpp:511] No credentials provided, authentication requests will be refused
I0608 11:41:28.014755  6182 authenticator.cpp:518] Initializing server SASL
I0608 11:41:28.017192  6181 group.cpp:349] Group process (group(1)@172.16.10.11:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.017233  6181 group.cpp:831] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0608 11:41:28.017242  6181 group.cpp:427] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.017684  6186 master.cpp:1650] Successfully attached file '/var/log/mesos/mesos-master.INFO'
I0608 11:41:28.017796  6186 contender.cpp:147] Joining the ZK group
I0608 11:41:28.018542  6186 group.cpp:349] Group process (group(4)@172.16.10.11:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.018571  6186 group.cpp:831] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0608 11:41:28.018579  6186 group.cpp:427] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.018890  6183 group.cpp:349] Group process (group(3)@172.16.10.11:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.018918  6183 group.cpp:831] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (1, 0, 0)
I0608 11:41:28.018928  6183 group.cpp:427] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.019326  6184 group.cpp:349] Group process (group(2)@172.16.10.11:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.019338  6184 group.cpp:831] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (1, 0, 0)
I0608 11:41:28.019343  6184 group.cpp:427] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.019915  6187 network.hpp:413] ZooKeeper group memberships changed
I0608 11:41:28.019966  6186 detector.cpp:152] Detected a new leader: (id='21')
I0608 11:41:28.019968  6181 group.cpp:700] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000020' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.020023  6186 group.cpp:700] Trying to get '/mesos/json.info_0000000021' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.022219  6182 contender.cpp:263] New candidate (id='29') has entered the contest for leadership
I0608 11:41:28.022341  6181 group.cpp:700] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000027' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.022517  6188 detector.cpp:479] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.0.1:5050) is detected
I0608 11:41:28.022569  6188 master.cpp:1711] The newly elected leader is master@127.0.0.1:5050 with id d34a6527-cd0d-4f74-8d5a-784488918f0c
I0608 11:41:28.023035  6185 network.hpp:461] ZooKeeper group PIDs: { log-replica(1)@127.0.0.1:5050, log-replica(1)@172.16.10.11:5050 }
E0608 11:41:28.023324  6189 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 24: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0608 11:41:28.023620  6181 network.hpp:413] ZooKeeper group memberships changed
I0608 11:41:28.023685  6182 group.cpp:700] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000020' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.024274  6182 group.cpp:700] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000027' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.024601  6182 group.cpp:700] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000028' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:28.024883  6182 network.hpp:461] ZooKeeper group PIDs: { log-replica(1)@127.0.0.1:5050, log-replica(1)@172.16.10.11:5050 }
E0608 11:41:28.025148  6189 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 24: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0608 11:41:36.008740  6183 network.hpp:413] ZooKeeper group memberships changed
I0608 11:41:36.008821  6186 group.cpp:700] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000020' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:36.009698  6186 group.cpp:700] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000028' in ZooKeeper
I0608 11:41:36.010126  6181 network.hpp:461] ZooKeeper group PIDs: { log-replica(1)@127.0.0.1:5050, log-replica(1)@172.16.10.11:5050 }
E0608 11:41:36.010527  6189 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 26: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I don't have other Mesos on the network, and my master has id `35069631-aace-4733-9440-60d9bc620d9a`

Edit : I add complete log

Comment: Hi, I just tried the setup and works nicely for me. Could you paste the complete Master log? One thing I am wondering about why you need zookeeper for the master in an non HA setup with only one master.

Comment: With 'I0608 11:41:28.022517  6188 detector.cpp:479] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.0.1:5050) is detected' it looks like there is another mesos running. Can you output  'ps aux | grep mesos'? Another simple attempt: Can you try to use `zk://172.16.10.11:2181/mesos2`?

Comment: If I use `mesos2` it works ! I try to find the master which is incorrectly configured with `ps -aux | grep mesos` but I don't find any other master...